# Loop through an Enumeration containing Header Names in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.1

I want to loop through an enumeration containing all of the header names inside a java servlet.  My code is as follows:

```
public class ServletParameterServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ServletConfig c = this.getServletConfig();
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.append("database: ").append(c.getInitParameter("database"))
              .append(", server: ").append(c.getInitParameter("server"));

       Enumeration<String> headerNames = ((HttpServletRequest) c).getHeaderNames();


    }
}
```

Is this the correct syntax?  How does one actually iterate over an enums values in Java?  And specifically in this instance?

Thanks for your help,
Marc

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you cast a ServletConfig to a HttpServletRequest?

Comment: That was eclipses suggestion :)  It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 11):

It's just an iteration like normal Java:

```
for (Enumeration<?> e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String nextHeaderName = (String) e.nextElement();
    String headerValue = request.getHeader(nextHeaderName);
}
```

Note that for some setups this is a bit dangerous in that HTTP headers can be duplicated.  In that case, the `headerValue` will be only the first HTTP header with that name.  Use `getHeaders` to get all of them.

And throw away whatever Eclipse was suggesting - it's garbage.

Answer (score 1):

we can use forEachRemaining

```
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    headerNames.asIterator().forEachRemaining(header -> {
         System.out.println("Header Name:" + header + "   " + "Header Value:" + request.getHeader(header));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to `List` by using the following method:

```
public static <T> List<T> enumerationToList(final Enumeration<T> enumeration) {
    if (enumeration == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return Collections.list(enumeration);
}
```

usage:

```
final List<String> headerNames = enumerationToList(request.getHeaderNames());

for (final String headerName : headerNames) {
    System.out.println(headerName);
}
```